# React - Only show item if variable is true

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to only show each instance of the `FeedTag` if `let soldOut` is false. How do I add this condition to each instance of the `FeedTag`? Each `product` in the `productList` has a `qty` and `soldout` prop and I only want to show a `<FeedTag>` where `qty` !== `soldout`.

```
  <div>
    {productList.length > 0 &&
      productList.map((product, i) => {
        let soldOut = (productList.qty = productList.soldout);
        return (
          <FeedTag
            data={product}
            name={product.headline}
            onSelect={(e) => onSelectProduct(e)}
            checked={seletedProductList.includes(product._id)}
            icon={<img src={helper.CampaignProductImagePath + product.image} alt="" />}
          />
        );
      })}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your assignment of `soldOut` (using `===`; I also renamed the variable to `available`) and use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html):

```
...
  const available = productList.qty !== productList.soldout;
  return (
    available && <FeedTag ... />
  );
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the products that are not sold out first, then map:

```
<div>
  {productList
    .filter((product) => product.qty !== product.soldout)
    .map((product) => (
      <FeedTag
        key={product._id}
        data={product}
        name={product.headline}
        onSelect={(e) => onSelectProduct(e)}
        checked={seletedProductList.includes(product._id)}
        icon={
          <img src={helper.CampaignProductImagePath + product.image} alt='' />
        }
      />
    ))}
</div>
```

Also don't forget the `key` attribute inside the map.